# How to define positive and negative integers and rational numbers in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I'm studying lambda calculus and only have basic knowledge about it. I read many of website and paper and understand the way that logic (T/F/and/or), predicate and successor work but I don't know how to accomplish other things in programming by using this lambda calculus.

I want to know how could I define positive and negative integers by using pairs of natural numbers and rational numbers as pairs of integers in lambda calculus.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look to the [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). For example, it defines integers as loop counters. Given a function `f` and a variable `x`, if:

- `x` is never mapped to `f`, it is an identity (equivalent of 0)
- `x` mapped once to `f`, which gives `f x`, it gives one loop count (1)
- `x` mapped two, which gives `f (f x)`, it is two loops (2); and so on.

The Church encoding defines signed numbers in terms of pairs. Therefore, using only functions, and combinations of them, the Church encoding encompasses arithmetics and logic.